# Title best practises

Tags: layout

My school has some really weird ideas on how the title for my seminar work has to look. How would I go on to create such a layout, while maintaining proper LaTeX best practises (i.e. using `\title`)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might take a look at the `titling` package, which has tools to customise the  `maketitle` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to *not* use `\title`.

A key-value syntax is much handier.

```
\documentclass{article}

% the following should go in a local class/package file
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Facharbeit}{m}
 {
  \begin{titlepage}
  \raggedright

  \keys_set:nn { facharbeit/titlepage } { #1 }
  
  \group_begin:
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \l_facharbeit_school_tl \\
  \l_facharbeit_address_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:

  \vspace*{\stretch{1}}

  \begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \LARGE Facharbeit \\
  \Large im~Seminarfach:~\l_facharbeit_seminar_tl
  \end{center}

  \vspace*{\stretch{1}}

  \begin{center}
  \l_facharbeit_title_tl
  \end{center}

  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}

  \group_begin:
  \bfseries
  Verfasser/in:~\l_facharbeit_author_tl
  \par\medskip
  Fachlehrer/in:~\l_facharbeit_teacher_tl
  \par\medskip
  Ausgabetermin:~\l_facharbeit_date_tl
  \par\medskip
  Abgabetermin:~\l_facharbeit_deadline_tl
  \group_end:

  \end{titlepage}
 }

\keys_define:nn { facharbeit/titlepage }
 {
  school   .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_school_tl,
  address  .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_address_tl,
  seminar  .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_seminar_tl,
  title    .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_title_tl,
  author   .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_author_tl,
  teacher  .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_teacher_tl,
  date     .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_date_tl,
  deadline .tl_set:N = \l_facharbeit_deadline_tl,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Facharbeit{
  school = School,
  address = Some street \\ Somecity,
  seminar = SF6,
  author = A. Uthor,
  teacher = T. Eacher,
  date = 28 February 2021,
  deadline = 28 February 2021,
  title = Besondere Primzahlen,
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are the man!

Comment: How would I pursue to create the second screenshot I have just uploaded - esepcially those signature lines?

Comment: Just use a couple of underscores. Or something like `\rule{4cm}{0.5pt}`

Comment: @timlwsk: Also, please keep it to one question per posting. Much easier to keep track of it that way.

Comment: @Ingmar I see, thank you!